# Centos 7 firewalld opened a port but cannot get connected

Tags: centos, port-forwarding, firewalld

I have port 5000 via the firewalld in centos 7 as shown below.

```
 firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: ens32
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http ssh
  ports: 5000/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  sourceports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Then I check my active zone  f

```
firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
public
```

Then I check the port itself

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --query-port=5000/tcp
yes
```

But when I telnet to the port 5000 is not responding what else could  be missing in terms of configuration ?

I have checked there is not other firewall cause when I run this systemctl stop firewalld all works fine.

Here is what and how I run the telnet commands

```
Microsoft Telnet> o *.*.*.*  5000
Connecting To *.*.*.*...Could not open connection to the host, on port  50
00: Connect failed
```

Comment: Try `firewall-cmd --reload`.  Is there something listening on port `5000`?

Comment: @val0x00ff yes its listening cause this gives me yes firewall-cmd --zone=public --query-port=5000/tcp

Comment: @val0x00ff if I off my firewall then it works

Comment: @user8012596, what give you `netstat -an|grep 5000`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I get this  netstat -an|grep 5000
tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have disabled selinux though  sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled

Comment: @user8012596 did you call `firewall-cmd --reload` command after adding the port? Also pass `--permanent` to `firewall-cmd` to persist the rule otherwise it won't survive reboots.

Comment: @val0x00ff yes i have done both and even reboot the server.

Comment: Please update your question and show the commands you are using. What is the output of these commands (telnet, journalctl, etc). Is there another firewall blocking? Are you trying to telnet from a remote location?

Comment: @val0x00ff ok I have updated my question and shown how I run telnet from a remove location which is windows. So when I off firewalld then all works fine.

Comment: @val0x00ff could it be because I am using telnet it got blocked me out due to the firewall settings?

Comment: Did you try disabling `Selinux` ?

Comment: Yes I have already disabled sestatus is disabled and I have even restarted the server too

Comment: @BOUKANDOURAMhamed the moment I run this systemctl stop firewalld all works well where I can telnet to the port accordingly.

Comment: try this : 
 `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5000/tcp --permanent`  `firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: @BOUKANDOURAMhamed I get this usage: see firewall-cmd man page
firewall-cmd: error: unrecognized arguments: firewall-cmd

Comment: If you're trying to excute `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5000/tcp --permanent firewall-cmd --reload` you need to add `;` (two commands) `firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5000/tcp --permanent;firewall-cmd --reload`

Comment: how many network interface you have ?

Comment: I get this for the command 
Warning: ALREADY_ENABLED: 5000:tcp
success
success

Comment: @BOUKANDOURAMhamed I have only one interface

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62508/discussion-between-boukandoura-mhamed-and-user8012596).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not able to connect to the port=5000 because the server is not listing on that port.

You can check on which port server is listing:

```
sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
sudo lsof -i:5000
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why, but when I execute this command:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --reload
```

It works.